# Where is <TeamCity Data Directory>/config/database.<database_type>.properties.dist?

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to migrate my TeamCity server to use SQL Server following the instructions at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Migrating+to+an+External+Database.

In step 3 it says

> Create a temporary properties file with a custom name (for example, database.database_type.properties) for the target database using the corresponding template (TeamCity Data Directory/config/database.database_type.properties.dist).

but I can't find `database.database_type.properties.dist` anywhere on disk or in the installer package.

Where is database.database_type.properties.dist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **database.<database_type>.properties.dist** where **<database_type>** in your case is **mssql**, so you should look for a file **database.mssql.properties.dist**.

The file is under <TeamCity data directory>/config. Path to the data directory you can see on Administration -> Global Settings page in TeamCity web interface.

Comment: Ah, I was looking in the server root under Program Files.